# set default checked value at total cost display without using "value"

Tags: javascript

As we can directly set the value to the value we wanted in the textbox like 
`<input type="text" name="total" value="500" size="10" readonly />`

Is there any method to display the default checked value in the text box wihout using value = "500"??

```js
var checks = document.getElementsByName('deliveryType');
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) checks[i].onclick = function() {
  var cal = document.getElementsByName('deliveryType');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
    if (cal[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<form id= selectEvent>
<section id="collection">
   
   <p>
   Home - &pound;500.00 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" data-price="500.00" checked />&nbsp; | &nbsp;
   self collect - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="ticketOffice" data-price="0" />
   </p>
  </section>
    
    <section id="checkCost">
   <h2>Total cost</h2>
   Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly />
  </section>
    </form>
```

Comment: `InputTextElement.defaultValue = 'whatever'`?

Comment: can you please demonstrate??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
var checks = document.getElementsByName('deliveryType'); 
checks.forEach(function(value){
    if(value.checked){
         document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + value.getAttribute('data-price');
    }
})
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) checks[i].onclick = function() {
  var cal = document.getElementsByName('deliveryType');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < cal.length; i++) {
    if (cal[i].checked) {
      total += parseFloat(cal[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
    }
  }
  document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
  
}
```

```html
<form id= selectEvent>
  <section id="collection">       
      <p>
      Home - &pound;500.00 <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="home" data-price="500.00" checked />&nbsp; | &nbsp;
      self collect - no charge <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="ticketOffice" data-price="0" />
      </p>
  </section>

<section id="checkCost">
      <h2>Total cost</h2>
      Total <input type="text" name="total" size="10" readonly />
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: that's work! is it the foreach function is checking is there any radio is ticked?? or can u please briefly explain for me?

Comment: simply looping through all the radio buttons for the checked one. If any checked radio button is found, grabbing the 'data-price' value for that radio. Then simply assign that into total. Hope that clears the code. Thanks.